# Filter output from multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-java

Suppose we have an array of scrips as such:

```
 ["xxxxx1","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx4"]
```

We have the following collections of scrips existing in db:

```
Executed:{"_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),"scrip" : "xxxxx1" },{"_id" : ObjectId("xxy"),"scrip" : "xxxxx3" }......
In-process:{"_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),"scrip" : "xxxxx4" }, ....
Rejected:{"_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),"scrip" : "xxxxx5" }....
```

We would like get the array of scrips not present in any of the collections above.
Expected output:

```
["xxxxx2"]
```

How can this be done in a single mongodb pipeline/query?

Comment: Can you elaborate the collection of scrips, does it comes from a query or are these array of objects as saved in a database

Comment: They are saved as an array of objects saved against a request - {  "requestid" : 'R1', "stocks" :  ["xxxxx1","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx4"]  }

Comment: what about "collections of scrips existing in db "how are they saved/fetched from a query? Are they arrays(Executed, Rejected, In-process) saved in a specific DB

Comment: You can $filter executed, rejected, in-process arrays then concat them, then $setDifference between stocks array and concated array

Comment: (Executed, Rejected, In-process)  are separate collections of scrip documents in the same db as the queried requests - structure being as shown above

Comment: Can you share db structure of above collections for ease of understanding

Comment: Executed:  

{"_id" : ObjectId("xxx"),"scrip" : "xxxxx1" }
{"_id" : ObjectId("xxy"),"scrip" : "xxxxx3" }
{"_id" : ObjectId("xyy"),"scrip" : "..." }

Comment: Is it possible to filter from multiple collections as part of the same aggregation pipleline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.executed.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "executedScrips":{
                $addToSet:"$scrip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"inprocess",
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":null,
                        "inprocessScrips":{
                            $addToSet:"$scrip"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"inprocessLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"rejected",
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":null,
                        "rejectedScrips":{
                            $addToSet:"$scrip"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"rejectedLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$inprocessLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$rejectedLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{  
            "scrips":{
                $concatArrays:[
                    "$executedScrips", 
                    {
                        $ifNull:["$inprocessLookup.inprocessScrips",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull:["$rejectedLookup.rejectedScrips",[]]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "notFound":{
                $setDifference:[["xxxxx1","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx4"],"$scrips"]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

## Data Set:

Collection: `executed`

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d60e572f00e0c8c3593b5ff"), "scrip" : "xxxxx1" }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d60e572f00e0c8c3593b600"), "scrip" : "xxxxx3" }
```

Collection: `inprocess`

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d60f23ff00e0c8c3593b601"), "scrip" : "xxxxx4" }
```

Collection: `rejected`

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5d60f260f00e0c8c3593b602"), "scrip" : "xxxxx5" }
```

## Output:

```
{ "notFound" : [ "xxxxx2" ] }
```

*Note: The query will fail if there are no records in `executed` collection as the aggregation starts from there.*

---

**Update I: The array of requests would be passed instead of an array of scrips**

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.executed.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":null,
            "executedScrips":{
                $addToSet:"$scrip"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"inprocess",
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":null,
                        "inprocessScrips":{
                            $addToSet:"$scrip"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"inprocessLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            "from":"rejected",
            "pipeline":[
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":null,
                        "rejectedScrips":{
                            $addToSet:"$scrip"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as":"rejectedLookup"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$inprocessLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind:{
            "path":"$rejectedLookup",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{  
            "scrips":{
                $concatArrays:[
                    "$executedScrips", 
                    {
                        $ifNull:["$inprocessLookup.inprocessScrips",[]]
                    },
                    {
                        $ifNull:["$rejectedLookup.rejectedScrips",[]]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            "requests":[
                {
                    "requestid" : "R1", 
                    "stocks" : ["xxxxx1","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx4"]
                },
                {
                    "requestid" : "R2", 
                    "stocks" : ["xxxxx1","xxxxx3","xxxxx4"]
                },
                {
                    "requestid" : "R3", 
                    "stocks" : ["xxxxx1","xxxxx3","xxxxx4","xxxxx10"]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "unmatchedRequests":{
               $map:{
                    "input":"$requests",
                    "as":"request",
                    "in":{
                        $concat:{
                            $cond:[
                                {
                                    $gt:[
                                        {
                                            $size:{
                                                $setDifference:["$$request.stocks","$scrips"]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        0
                                    ]
                                },
                                "$$request.requestid",
                                null
                            ]
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "unmatchedRequests":{
                $filter:{
                    "input":"$unmatchedRequests",
                    "as":"unmatchedRequest",
                    "cond":{
                        $ne:["$$unmatchedRequest",null]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Output:**

```
{ "unmatchedRequests" : [ "R1", "R3" ] }
```

**Note: In the 7th aggregation stage, we are injecting the array of requests.**

Comment: Will try this !!Appreciate this .If we were to get the array of requests  having atleast one scrip unmatched instead - each request being { "requestid" : 'R1', "stocks" : ["xxxxx1","xxxxx2","xxxxx3","xxxxx4"] } ;how can this be tweaked

Comment: @IUnknown Sorry but didn't get you completely. You need this ```unmatched scrip(s)```  info for each request right?

Comment: array of requests having atleast one scrip unmatched (instead of array of constituent scrips for the request).So the expected output will be ['R1']

Comment: @IUnknown Added the mongo query for the new requirement.

Comment: How does addfield works if i need to pull in the request collection ,instead of injecting hardcoded documents

Comment: @IUnknown You can look up into the request collection to get that data.

Comment: How do we lookup without any foreign  field connect .We are practically pulling the entire requests collection

Comment: With mongo 3.6+, we can also perform uncorrelated queries in lookup. Please check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ for more info.

Comment: Would there be a way to merge the second last and last step and  filter non-null entries - rather than another parse of the array for null

Comment: @IUnknown The ```$map``` applies an expression to each item in an array and returns an array with the applied results i.e it's one to one mapping. The filtering cannot be done at this stage.